# "KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'" message when updating Anaconda packahes on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

Each time I try to update my Anaconda (version 3.15.1) packages on my Mac (OS X 10.10.4), I get the following message:

`Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback: 
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'`

The rest of the updating process seems to run normally, but I'd like to figure out what causes this message and how to remove it.

Comment: I am guessing the issue might be coming from a line like - `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` which is trying to look up the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` , but that is clearly not set.Do what that error message says and set `PYTHONVERBOSE` for the complete traceback.

Comment: I did `set PYTHONVERBOSE 1` and then ran `conda update --all` again, and I get nothing more than the previous message.

Comment: The command to set the variable on OS X is `export PYTHONVERBOSE=1`, or just set it on the same line as conda, like `PYTHONVERBOSE=1 conda update --all`.

Answer (score 5):

Set the PYTHONVERBOSE environment variable as suggested by the error message:

```
PYTHONVERBOSE=1 conda update --all
```

That should give you a full traceback, which should tell you what file that error is coming from.